# SQL Date/Time Format

Tags: sql

How to convert date/time from `20150323153528` to `2015-03-23 15:35:28.000`. I need this to filter based on the `getdate()`.  Thanks in advance.

```
Select * from table
Where 20150323153528 > GETDATE() -  7
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: `Getdate` is product specific. Tag the dbms you are using...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Statement to convert date to your requirement

```
DECLARE @Date varchar(20) = '20150323153528'


Select * from table Where

       CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), @Date), 121) + ' ' + stuff(stuff(right('000000' + cast(@Date as varchar),6),5,0,':'),3,0,':') as DATETIME > GETDATE() - 7
```

Comment: Thanks all.  Using SQL server 2012.  mohan11 - by formatting date would that slow down the query process?

Answer (score 0):

Note: I assume this is a Microsoft SQL Server environment using T-SQL:

The formatting of `date` / `datetime` values is not a concern of T-SQL. You should do that in your presentation-layer (i.e. your frontend code).

If you have date/time values represented as integers of the form `20150323153528` then you cannot use them in T-SQL. You need to convert them to strings (preferably in ISO-8601 format) for SQL Server to successfully internally convert them to `datetime` (or `datetimeoffset`) values which can then be compared with other `datetime` values.

I suggest performing the conversion in your application code before you send it to SQL, as a `datetime`-typed parameter value, like so:

```
Int32 weirdDateValue = 20150323153528;
String s = weirdDateValue.ToString( CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );
String dtValueAsIso8601 = String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2} {3}:{4}:{5}.{6}", 
    s.Substring(0, 4), s.Substring(4, 2), s.Substring(6, 2),
    s.Substring(8, 2), s.Substring(10, 2), s.Substring(12, 2), s.Substring(14) 
);

DateTime dtValue = DateTime.ParseExact( dtValueAsIso8601, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff" );

cmd.Parameters.Add("@dtValue", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dtValue;
```

In T-SQL the process is pretty much the same, except using `MID` - note that `MID` uses 1-based character indexes instead of 0-based:

```
DECLARE @input int           = 20150323153528
DECLARE @s     varchar( 14 ) = CONVERT( @input, nvarchar(14) )
DECLARE @dtStr varchar( 24 ) = MID( @s, 1, 2 ) + '-' + MID( @s, 3, 2 ) + '-' + MID( @s, 5, 2 ) + ' ' + -- etc...
DECLARE @dt    datetime      = CONVERT( @dtStr, datetime )

SELECT
    *
FROM
    [table]
WHERE
    @dt > GETDATE() - 7
```

If the integer values are stored in an actual column instead of a parameter you'll need to convert the logic into a scalar UDF which performs the conversion. I strongly suggest you change the table's design to add a strongly-typed `datetime` column and permanently store the value there, and then drop the datetime-as-int column:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ConvertIntDateIntoDateTime(@dateAsInt int) RETURNS datetime AS
BEGIN

    -- same code as above minus the SELECT statement
    RETURN @dt

END
```

Used in an inner subquery to allow the data to be accessed in `WHERE` statements, like so:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *,
            dbo.ConvertIntDateIntoDateTime( someDateColumn ) AS someDateColumn2
        FROM
            [table]
    ) AS FixedTable
WHERE
    FixedTable.someDateColumn2 > GETDATE() - 7
```

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL you could use

```
DECLARE @Date varchar(20) = '20150323153528'

Select * from table Where CAST(convert(varchar,@Date) as datetime) > GETDATE() - 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read this [page](https://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/).

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 120) — yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss(24h)
```